# Unable to resolve host name on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am trying to reach an API which is deployed on an EC2 server.

```
req = requests.post(http://xxxxx:10002/scan, json=d)
# xxxxx is the EC2 server hostname
```

When I execute the code on my machine it works fine.
But when I try it on AWS Lambda it returns this error

```
 "errorMessage": "HTTPConnectionPool(host=host, port=10002): Max retries exceeded with url: /scan_ea (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2000b81e48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",
  "errorType": "ConnectionError"
```

I doubt a network error but I dont understand why is it working on my machine. I didnt do any particular network configurations before executing the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the lambda in a private vpc?

Comment: No it isnt. Should it be in the same VPC as the EC2 that hosts the api ?

Comment: I justed updated my question with more details

Comment: Lambdas in a VPC (as you said it's in the same VPC as the EC2 instance) dont regularly have internet access (you'd need a NAT gateway for that). So make sure to use the private IP / DNS of the EC2 instance, not the public one, to be routed internally. [More on Lambda Internet Connectivity in VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: @rauberdaniel thanks. So I replaced the hostname by the EC2 private ip: requests.post(http://xx.xx.xx.xx:10002/scan, json=d) and I am now having a connection timeout (still no VPC configs done for lambda). Do you know what should I do please ?

Comment: If the `http://xxxxx:10002` endpoint is public and can be resolved and reached from your laptop over the public internet (no VPN or other private routing) then it should be resolvable and reachable from a Lambda function, unless that Lambda function runs in VPC and you have not set up routing correctly. If the endpoint is publicly available then you don't need to configure your Lambda to run in VPC (unless it also connects to other resources that are private inside the VPC).

Comment: It is reachable from my laptop but it is not from lambda (without vpc configs).

Comment: Without a complete setup it's almost impossible to determine what's happening here: Either your lambda function lives in a subnet that doesn't have an NATGW attached (you'll need to attach a NAT gateway) or whatever you're attempting to connect to requires a whitelisted IP / host

Comment: Have you checked if the lambda's security group has outbound rules open to reach the destination server?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @ORP you was right, the lambda SG was not allowing traffic to/within server on port 10002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @ORP suggested, I only had to check lambda's SG and inbound/outbound rules were not allowing traffic to port 10002